# Show GIF Image during rendering

Tags: javascript, animation, progress-bar, loading

In my application am building some large object which takes 10 - 15 seconds during that time i want to show some loading icon. Is there any way to do that. When i show some GIF image it is not animating.

Any trick to animate this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure CSS animation. There are a lot of generators, for example http://cssload.net/

Comment: Thank you . Let me try that out